# Pin 'Favourite tags' on top of sidebar?

Tags: support, tag-watching

Is there any way to pin the 'Favourite tags' on Stackoverflow on top of the right sidebar for every page load?

Comment: Not without a userscript no; and I'm not aware of an existing one that does this. I can't imagine it being too difficult to create one though.